# Has any superhero attempted suicide because they've "had enough"?

Tags: super-hero

In the various superhero universes, has there been any superhero who has deliberately committed suicide because they have had enough?

I will accept any answers where any superhero has committed suicide, along with their reasons to do so.

Comment: https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/gen-discussion-1/has-any-superhero-committed-suicide-1523908/

Comment: @Valorum, suicide through depression.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/comicbooks/comments/2ncf04/what_superheroes_have_committed_suicide_or_tried/

Comment: This is far too broad. There are literally [hundreds of examples](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/gen-discussion-1/has-any-superhero-committed-suicide-1523908/) across dozens of properties.

Comment: @Valorum, I can't find anyone who has done what I am asking?

Comment: As of right now, your last sentence is basically "any superhero who has committed suicide or hasn't", which is all of them. What do you mean by the second clause, superheroes who chose to try, but didn't? Considered it but didn't go through with it?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, there are people who try to commit suicide but don't, why did they not commit suicide?

Comment: Would you consider restricting this to people who actually succeeded in committing suicide, due to being tired of living? That'd narrow the scope and make it more suitable for good answers (not that existing ones aren't good enough already).

Comment: @Gallifreyan, if you want to edit it to that effect I would not complain.

Comment: If you want a recent example, just watch _Logan_

Comment: It's closed now, but http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Chloe would probably be an example too.

Answer (score 13):

[Element Girl (Urania Blackwell)](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/element-girl/4005-45403/) was written into an issue of *The Sandman* titled *Façade*<sup>1</sup>, during which she ended her own life.

Most of the story involves a retired Element Girl trying to get by and pass for normal.

[image: "I smoke a cigarette and pretend I'm normal. And I wish I was dead."]

She can't really turn off her powers, and at best she can only "fake" being normal for a certain amount of time.

This is punctuated by a trip out to a restaurant to meet a friend, where she builds a human looking facade by building hair out of metal and a skin-tone face out of a polymer. The polymer hardens too quickly and her fake face literally falls off into her meal, causing her to flee back to her apartment in shame.

Towards the end, Death happens to wander by her building on an unrelated matter and have a heart to heart with her.

[image: "But... How do you know that? There was nobody there. Only Rex and Me. No one else." "Me." "...Who are you?" "Don't you know?" "Yes. I think I do. And you've come for me? Blessed, merciful Death. You've come to make it all stop?"]

Element Girl petitions Ra to end her powers (and her life), and he does so, and her body crumbles into dust with Death as the only witness to her passing.

[image: "I never realized before. The Sun. It's just a mask, too. And the face behind it... It's beatufil. It's...]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *The Sandman* #20, collected in *The Dream Country* and in *Absolute Death* (*Death: The Deluxe Edition*)</sub>

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best one. Not only because she is very graphically shown as a tormented soul in the comic, but because [DC and the readers had forgotten](https://dcmultiversehistorian.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/is-there-a-connection-between-elemental-woman-and-metamorpho/) about Element Girl by that time. There's also a nice moment in the comic when Death says Ra keeps creating metamorphs to battle Apep, unwilling to believe that Death took Apep 3 millennia ago. Nice stuff... _sobs_

Comment: @Gallifreyan - *Sandman* always knew how to get you in the heart.

Answer (score 11):

Until it was retconned as being the result of psychic influence, in February 2014's *Judge Dredd Megazine* #345, [Judge Anderson](http://judgedredd.wikia.com/wiki/Cassandra_Anderson) hung herself in the *Judge Dredd* comics. Given she was an empath, it was heavily implied that she did it as a result of the Day of Chaos where a billion people died and she likely felt their deaths.

[image: Hanging Judge Anderson]

Prior to her, her partner, Judge Corey, similarly committed suicide in 1989.

[image: Corey clearing her head]

Answer (score 9):

Adrian Chase, one of the incarnations of [Vigilante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigilante_(comics)#Adrian_Chase) also committed suicide in *Vigilante #50* in February 1988.

> As the series progressed Chase became ever more conflicted over his role as Vigilante, the violence he engaged in, and the harm he caused to those around him. He also became increasingly mentally unstable—alternating between bouts of enraged violence, paranoia, and terrible remorse for his actions. Near the end, he even resorted to murdering innocent police officers who got in his way. His mounting guilt culminated in the final issue of his series (#50) where, after contemplating the course of his life, Chase committed suicide.

[image: Adrian Chase suicide]